# switch tabs in fragmentactivity

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I know it sounds stupid but I recently started studying fragments/fragmentactivity to replace tabactivity.. but the simple problem is that I don't know how to switch the tab from current tab i.e. in tabactivity hosting activities, used this to open tab 1

```
TabActivity tabMap = (TabActivity) getParent();
tabMap.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
```

How can I do the same with FragmentActivity hosting tabs (fragments)??

Thanks

Comment: Why not read this? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Comment: Yeah I would navigate the tabs if I had used the actionbar tabs, I've used the custom tabs, I'll post the code once I get back to my place, sorry for not mentioning that part,  thanks anyway

Comment: I followed [this](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/)

Comment: If the above code sets the current tab "indicator" in your tabhost, I think also you  need to set the current fragment into container by FragmentTransaction as well. Did you consider using ActionBarSherlock, or it's not the case where you would need it?

Comment: yes I'm using Actionbarsherlock, but I haven't used that particular addition of tabs in actionbar (which is really the best way to use it), but now I want to know how to switch another tab from already opened tab like we do in tabactivity, next time I'll remember adding tabs in actionbar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as I understood, you want something like this (assuming getParent() returns Activity)

```
TabHost host = getParent().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
host.setCurrentTab(1);
```

BTW, switching to ActionBar tabs is recommended, not hard and it will look much better and you would'nt have to use deprecated stuff.

Comment: thanks Doctoror just by chaning getParent() to getActivity() did it.. I didn't know that would be this much easy, I did stick to the old fashioned tab switch.. (AND definitely would switch to actionbar tabs)

Comment: Yes, actually getActivity() from a Fragment. I thought that getParent() was your method or something you implemented :)